# Decimal-module is not working on binary level? How?

Tags: python, module, floating-point, binary, decimal

I'm a beginner when it comes to what's going on in the background when I start the program. Right now my focus is on the difference between "decimal" and "float" in "Python". I read the following article about this:

[Decimal vs float in Python](https://blog.tecladocode.com/decimal-vs-float-in-python/)

Yes, I now know what "decimal" does and how you can use this module. However, I asked after the following sentence how "decimal" works at all:

***"Unlike floats, the decimal objects defined in the decimal module are not prone to this loss of precision, because they don't rely on binary fractions."***

As far as I know, the computer can only work with the binary number system. So my question is: How does the computer handle and work with the module "decimal" when it is not processing on binary level?

Comment: "not prone to this loss of precision, because they don't rely on binary fractions" oversimplifies   base2/base10 issues to the point that it is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In this context "binary fractions" - is a method to store floating point values in memory. Or to be more precise, to represent a floating point number of any base as a binary.
Yes, everything is stored as a binary and computer does operate binaries on the low level.
However, on the high level we rarely work with binary exclusivelly. We use strings, integer, floats etc. - which are just a convinient abstraction to make it easier for humans to work with it.

So back to your question:

Python's `float` does store it's value as a binary representation. And that is exactly the reason why it may produce precision artifacts.

Decimal, on the other hand, does not opearate a floating point number as a whole. It keeps all parts of number separately and then operates them individually.
And don't forget, `Decimal` - is a class, not a atomary type.

Here is a snippet from Decimal's source:

```
    if intpart is not None:
        # finite number
        fracpart = m.group('frac') or ''
        exp = int(m.group('exp') or '0')
        self._int = str(int(intpart+fracpart))
        self._exp = exp - len(fracpart)
        self._is_special = False
```

As you can see, it retrieves integer, exponent and other utility data and stores them idividually.

Decimal's precision is achieved at cost of computational and memory resources.